# Email Greeting in Journey Builder giving a Set Script error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I am currently trying to set up a journey using a few different emails in the campaign, but every single email that I have placed in this journey comes up with this error message. [image]

I have used this greeting formula:

`%%[ IF NOT EMPTY(FirstName) THEN SET @message = FirstName ELSEIF NOT EMPTY(LastName) THEN SET @message = LastName ELSE SET @message = “there” ENDIF ]%% Hello %%=v(@message)=%%,`

I have used this in many different campaigns and email sends but for some reason when in this particular email, its not registering/validating. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Curly brackets won't work in AMPscript syntax.

I'd write it like this:

```ampscript
%%[ 

set @firstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")
set @LastName= AttributeValue("LastName")

IF NOT EMPTY(@firstName) THEN 

  SET @message = @firstName 

ELSEIF NOT EMPTY(@lastName) THEN 

  SET @message = @lastName

ELSE 

  SET @message = "there"

ENDIF 

]%%
Hello %%=v(@message)=%%,
```